Units of "minimum size" when drawing a named rectangle in TikZ
When drawing a rectangle using \node and minimum width/height, the size of the resulting rectangle is different from one drawn with \draw … rectangle …. I need the \node so I can refer to it by name.
I understand that I can fix this by adding the units to all sizes (10mm, 15mm), but I'm trying to understand why it doesn't work without. I assumed the default units of <dimension> was points.
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x = 1mm, y = 1mm]

  %% named rectangle with minimum size of 10x15.
  \node[%
  minimum width = 10,
  minimum height = 15,
  draw = blue
  ]
  (rect) at (0,0) {};

  %% unnamed rectangle with size of 10x15.
  \draw [red] (0,0) rectangle  ++(10, 15);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Hello and welcome. The minimum height and minimum width options require a length with a unit. When the unit is not specified, tikz defaults to pt. The x= and y= options have only one action, that of modifying the coordinate system's default unit of measurement, which is cm and not pt! Parameters requiring lengths are not affected by the coordinate system. So there are no errors here.

This is related to transformations in tikz (see PFG manual page 373). One paragraph explicitly states:

The most important aspect of the coordinate transformation [...] is that it applies to coordinates only!

Node dimensions are not affected by transformations and the default unit is pt. If you want dimensions to work as if mm are used, add scale and transform shape to options of every affected node or use global options. See the example below
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    x = 1mm, y = 1mm,
    every node/.style = {
        transform shape,
        scale = 2.84,   % Converts mm to pt by the factor 72.27/25.4
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  %% named rectangle with minimum size of 10x15.
  \node[%
    minimum width = 10,
    minimum height = 15,
    draw = blue,
  ] (rect) at (0,0) {};
  %% unnamed rectangle with size of 10x15.
  \draw [red] (0,0) rectangle  ++(10, 15);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


